# How to apply a different color to the face of part of an object

Tags: edit-mode

[image]I have created a simple small (10 metres long) girder bridge which is made up of a base, hand rails and the vertical girders between the base and hand rails all using separate using mesh cubes. I firstly set the color of all of the object to a galvanised color and then decided to color the walkway (top face of the base) near black to represent a non slip rubber surface. I have added another material set to near black color and then attempted to add it to the top face of the base. With 'face select' selected it doesn't matter which face I select in edit mode as soon as I then select my 'black' material ALL of that part of the object changes color. How can I apply it only to one face.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You changed the material in the first slot to a different material - but you have to keep the first material if the rest of the object should stay as it is.

The way it should work is: you have to add a second material slot by pressing the *Plus* button right to the material slots. Then create or select a second material for the second slot. Now if you have two materials, usually the first material is applied to everything until you tell Blender differently. So, to change a single face for example, select that face in *Edit Mode*, go to the materials tab, select the material this face should have and click the *Assign* button below the material slots. This assigns the selected material to selected faces.

[image: assign material]

Comment: Thanks but I did add another material so that I now have two one I named material.galvanised set to a grey color 'base color) and the second I named as material.black walkway set to a near black 'base color. Then I select the face I want black and select 'material black walkway. See new image now added to question.     I NOW see that I was assigning incorrectly. I created the new material BEFORE I attempted to change the color to the face. I now select the face THEN add the material and assign - tricky.

Comment: @JohnArnold It's not necessary to first select the face. Actually you can take an object and if you know you want to add 5 materials to different faces but you don't know which faces at that moment, you can add the 5 materials to the object right from the start and later decide which faces to assign them to. Only the material in the first slot is assigned to the whole mesh by default, if you didn't select faces and assigned them different materials. Or you can even assign empty material slots to faces, if you want to create the materials later.

Comment: @JohnArnold Looking at your new screenshot - as I said in my answer, you have to add another material slot with the Plus button. Having two or more materials in your file doesn't give the object a second material. You need to create a slot, so that the object can have multiple materials at the same time. What you are doing in your new screenshot is using the single material slot and exchanging one material for the other. Take a look at my screenshot - I have two materials in the list where you have only one.

Comment: As mentioned earlier I added a new material to my list (using the + button) BEFORE I selected a face and then selected that material from the list (which contained the two materials) yet it still applied that (selected) material to ALL faces not just the one I had selected. Anyway I have now achieved what I wanted to do and the top face of the bottom of the bridge is black (and the other faces are grey). It only seemed to work correctly when I added a material (+ button) AFTER I selected the face.

Comment: It may seem like that but that's not how it works. You're mixing up materials and material slots. The dropdown list doesn't show the materials of the object, but all materials in the file. None of your screenshots shows two material slots on your selected object. If you had started with an object that has NO material by default (a plane for example, while a cube comes with a default material), hitting Plus will add the first material. If you want different materials you have to hit the Plus again for a second material. I supposed your object already had a first material, the galvanised metal.

Comment: Thanks. I have used multiple texture images before and never had this problem. I assume the process is the same and do (it seems) forgot what I did before. All is well now thanks.

Comment: You can have multiple image textures in just a single material, that's also something completely different than multiple materials...