# Blend different objects of the Bevel Object of a Bezier Curve from Start to End?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I hope I will be clear in the question as English is not my native language.

I am designing Surf Board on Blender, and then CNC them.

I changed quite a lot my process to work with Blender lately to be more efficient and resulting with a better topology.

My process for the one "rail" (then I can do mirror on X) :

- Creating the "Outline" curve
- Creating the "Rail" curve, which will be the Bevel object of the Outline Curve
- Creating the "Scoop" curve, which will be the Curve Modifier object of the Outline.

Outline of the Board :
[image: Outline Surf Board]
Scoop of the Board :
[image: Scoop Surf Board]
The result with 1 curve for the rail :
[image: Resulting Rail]

The problem is that the rail are not the same from the tail to the nose.

I would like to know how to change the Bevel object along the Curve it applied to ? If it's possible, or what would be your preferred workaround ?

I can work with 2-5 control points / Bevel objects along the curve, and so the resulting Bevel would "blend" between the transition of the Bevel Object.

A possible workaround I'm thinking would be to split the Outline Curve into 5 segments, and apply different Bevel object on each segments, and maybe for the blending part with some Loop Tools ?

Result with a Rail with 2 segments :
[image: Rails 2 Segments]

I'm a bit lost on a clean solution / workaround for this one ? What do you think ?

Have a good day

## Test of the solution from StefLancien with NURBS Surface

[image: NURBS Surface 1]
[image: NURBS Surface 2]

It works like a charm after understanding the NURBS Surface.

## Test of the solution from Alex with Higgsas Loft Splines Geometry Nodes :

[image: Higgsas Loft Splines Geometry Nodes]

This will work pretty well FMPOV. I am creating my different segments of rails, then apply the Higgsas Loft Splines geometry nodes, then the curve modifier for the Outline. I don't need the Scoop curve anymore because the information is already embedded in the different segments rails.

Comment: I would recommend to use NUBRS surfaces instead of multiple curves ? You can have a look here : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/312103/177431

Comment: Ok. NUBRS surfaces would modelize all the "rail" and differents curves into one NUBRS surface ? I'm not familiar with it and it seems a bit complicated to work with it ?

Comment: Ok, I watched some yt videos and it helped me a lot to understand how to manipulate and edit the NURBS surface. It seems extremely powerful. I love blender... thank you for the tips !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using [Higgsas loft spline node](https://blenderartists.org/t/higgsas-geometry-nodes-groups-blender-3-3-3-4-3-5-3-6-4-0/1351737/75)

With it, you can create a surface by blending different profiles

[image]

Comment: Awesome ! I will give it a try ! Thanks